# Is there a document for mongoose callback?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

As the title, I don't know how many arguments and what are they. So i cannot define callbacks correctly. I didn't find such document on mongoose website, nor google. Please help.

Comment: You typically have to look in the code examples for the method in the documentation.

Comment: I hope there is a more formal way...